# JIRA REST API FOR EXCEL EXPORT

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I need to export details of a project into a excel. Is there any API which will export JIRA details to EXCEL?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, things you have tried, results of your investigation, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

JIRA has a REST API and the generic Web Data Connector inside Excel will happily connect, make a query based on the criteria you specify in the URL, and convert the returned JSON data into a table of data in Excel.